# How to block access to Crawlers to any Image on a Private page

Tags: private, google-search, search-engines

We found out that a reverse image search on google images was able to link to a set of images that are on Private Pages.

Is there a plugin that can fully protect these images? 
if not what coding technique can achieve this wizardry?

Comment: You can try to use robots.txt methods to block crawlers on indexing certain folders or images. https://varvy.com/robottxt.html

Comment: i think this will do the trick! https://wordpress.org/plugins/private-uploads/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a plugin, but if you could just add the img URLs to your Disallows in robots.txt.

Also, Google is probably getting the image URL from the image sitemap.